# QProgressDialog: problems about MinimumDuration

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qprogressbar

I'm using QT 4.8.5. I met some problems on QProgressDialog with MinimumDuration.
Here is the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#minimumDuration-prop.

1.Test with the following code. The dialog is not displayed at all. But the documentation says: "***the dialog will pop up after the minimumDuration time*** or as soon as any progress is set".

```
QProgressDialog* dlg = new QProgressDialog("Test", "cancel", 0, 10);
dlg->setMinimumDuration(8000);
```

2.Test with the following code. The dialog is displayed in 8 seconds. But the documentation says: "the dialog will pop up after the minimumDuration time or ***as soon as any progress is set***". Though the behavior is different with the documentation, I think the current behavior is acceptable.

```
QProgressDialog* dlg = new QProgressDialog("Test", "cancel", 0, 10);
dlg->setMinimumDuration(8000);
dlg->setValue(0);
```

3.Test with the following code. The dialog is never displayed. But the documentation says: "***the dialog will pop up after the minimumDuration time or as soon as any progress is set***".

```
QProgressDialog* dlg = new QProgressDialog("Test", "cancel", 0, 10);
dlg->setMinimumDuration(8000);
dlg->setValue(1);
```

4.Test with the following code. The behavior is same as item 2.

```
QProgressDialog* dlg = new QProgressDialog("Test", "cancel", 0, 10);
dlg->setMinimumDuration(8000);
dlg->setValue(0);
dlg->setValue(1);
```

5.Test with the following code. The dialog is displayed as soon as set the progress value to 1. Why does Sleep() function affect the behavior here?

```
QProgressDialog* dlg = new QProgressDialog("Test", "cancel", 0, 10);
dlg->setMinimumDuration(8000);
dlg->setValue(0);
::Sleep(static_cast<DWORD>(1000));
dlg->setValue(1);
```

6.Test with the code below. The dialog is displayed immediately, but I set MinimumDuration to 5. Is it a problem?

```
QProgressDialog* dialog = new QProgressDialog("Message", "Close", 1, 10);
dialog->setMinimumDuration(5000);
dialog->setValue(0); 
dialog->setValue(1);
```

I test on Windoes 7. What are the issues? What are the correct behaviors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed the information is scattered around so it seems to make no sense. But there is a [precious hint in the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#details) :

> QProgressDialog ... estimates the time the operation will take
>   (***based on time for steps***), and only shows itself if that
>   estimate is beyond minimumDuration() (4 seconds by default).

The dialog seems to use the `value` property to approximate the time required for steps. And it is seems that value property by default is not set

[value property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#value-prop) :

> For the progress dialog to work as expected, you should initially set
>   this property to 0 and finally set it to QProgressDialog::maximum();

Indeed, `dialog->value()` returns -1 in my machine after construction.

To wrap up :

1. Not setting value is an issue. You **have to set** value sometimes to make it work.
2. **The dialog is shown as soon as it interpolates that the *total amount* of work is going to take more than minimumDuration**
3. Setting a value to anything lower than `QProgressDialog::minimum()`, which is the case by default, causes the progressbar to stay hidden.
4. Your second cases set the value to  `0 = minimum`. After 8 seconds, you still havent updated that value. which means the processing of a single item take more than 8 seconds. Should show.
5. You **should** modify the value from `0 -> minimum -> maximum` for proper behavior. Your third case, fail to do this because value goes from -1 to 1, without being set to 0 = minimum. Unspecified, in this version doesnt show.
6. Your 4th case means "the first processing took 0 second, the second is not done yet". So the minimumDuration behavior kicks in. Should show.
7. **Now that there is one second duration for the first task (case 5)**, the dialog **approximates** that 10 tasks are going to take 10s, which is bigger than `8s`, so the dialog is shown as soon as `dlg->setValue(1);` is executed.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks @UmNyobe.

Comment: Hi UmNyobe, I get one more problem with this: Test with the code below. The dialog is displayed immediately, but I set MinimumDuration to 5. Is it a problem?

QProgressDialog* dialog = new QProgressDialog("Message", "Close", 1, 10);
dialog->setMinimumDuration(5);
dialog->setValue(1);

Comment: remember that the duration is in milliseconds.

Comment: Sorry, It's a typo. My intention was set minimum duration to 5000. The dialog is displayed immediately.

Answer (score 3):

I tested this on OS X, with Qt 5 and get the same results

Looking closer at the documentation for [setValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html#value-prop), it states: -

> For the progress dialog to work as expected, you should initially set this property to QProgressDialog::minimum() and finally set it to QProgressDialog::maximum(); you can call setValue() any number of times in-between.

With this in mind, it works as expected, as can be seen when you first set the value to zero, then another value.

```
QProgressDialog* dlg = new QProgressDialog("Test", "cancel", 0, 10);
dlg->setMinimumDuration(8000);
dlg->setValue(0);
dlg->setValue(1);
```

So, I think the documentation for setMinimumDuration should probably link to this too, but the behaviour is correct according to the documentation, when taking setValue into account.

Comment: Thanks TheDarkKnight.